# EF Fails but ADO Executes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm building a ASP.NET Core Web API for .NET 7 and I am trying to create a controller for the `AspNetRoleClaims` table.

In my appsettings.Development.json I have the following:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnectionString": "Server=localhost;Database=BaseStack;User Id=BaseStackAdmin;Password=redacted-password;TrustServerCertificate=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
  }
}
```

In my Program.cs, view model, and controller endpoint I have the following:

```c#
// Program.cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnectionString"));

// view model
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace BaseStack.Models;

[Table("AspNetRoleClaims")]
public class AspNetRoleClaim
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? ClaimType { get; set; }
    public string? ClaimValue { get; set; }
}

// endpoint
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AspNetRoleClaim>>> GetAll()
{
    if (_context.AspNetRoleClaims == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return await _context.AspNetRoleClaims.ToListAsync();
}
```

However, this fails when I try to hit the endpoint with the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

What is odd is that if I replace everything in the `GetAll` method with the ADO.NET equivalent, it works just fine:

```c#
var aspNetRoleClaims = new List<AspNetRoleClaim>();
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString")))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM AspNetRoleClaims;";

    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        connection.Open();
    }

    using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SingleResult | CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            aspNetRoleClaims.Add(new AspNetRoleClaim()
            {
                Id = reader.GetInt32("Id"),
                RoleId = reader.GetString("RoleId"),
                ClaimType = reader.GetString("ClaimType"),
                ClaimValue = reader.GetString("ClaimValue")
            });
        }
    }
}

return aspNetRoleClaims;
```

At first I thought it might have been my connection string but if it was then I would have expected the ADO.NET equivalent to fail.

Comment: Queries are not the same when using different drivers.  ADO driver interface is not the same as EntityFramework interface.  Simple queries like "SELECT * FROM AspNetRoleClaims;" should work for both ADO and EntityFramework.  Entity there is a mapping file between c# classes and database tables/field.  If ADO works than maybe you need to use Migration to update the Entity mapping file.  The Entity Model (mapping) is AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>

Comment: Seems like connection string issue. Have you tried hard code the connection string in to program.cs and see if it works? Helps to clarify where the issue actually is.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang - If you want to answer the question, I will rep and accept. After taking your suggestion of hardcoding the connection string, I realized that I was not actually using the connection string defined in my appsettings rather it was using the string literal "DefaultConnectionString". The change was to use: `options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString"))`

Comment: @Charlieface - that is ultimately what I did, yes.